# Website doesn't show real resolution on mobile (Bootstrap , maybe?)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, resolution

I made a responsive website with bootstrap, jquery, css, etc.. And when I check on my PC browser it adapts itself to any resolution like it should.  The problem is when I go to my mobile browser and check the website, it shows the page like its resolution is 800px approx. So it shows small fonts, small buttons and the navbar doesn't collapse. When I check my mobile resolution on http://www.mydevice.io/ it says the resolution is 320px. So it should show the navbar collapsed at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably forgotten to add the meta code for responsive media queries.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you both.. .. that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this links in your Master(Layout) page between header tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: Thank you both.. .. that was it.